# Itemized Arabic text has different margin indentations when using babel and arabluatex

Tags: babel, enumitem, arabic, arabluatex

Why don't the bullets of the Arabic text written by the aid of `babel` align with the right margin unlike the case of using `arabluatex`?

How to make them in case of `babel` align with the right margin?

---

### babel

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem, ulem}
\usepackage[english, bidi = basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = ids fonts]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Scheherazade}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
    \begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
        \textbf{\uline{%
                قواعد هامة:%
        }}
        \begin{itemize}[
            label = \textbullet, leftmargin=*, labelsep = 0.5ex, itemsep = 0\baselineskip, %nosep
            topsep = 0.5\baselineskip, font=\bfseries, before=\bfseries,
            ]
            \item الأول
            \item الثاني
        \end{itemize}%
    \end{otherlanguage}%
\end{document}
```

---

### arabluatex

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem, ulem}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Scheherazade}[ Script = Arabic, RawFeature={+anum}]
\usepackage{arabluatex}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
    \begin{txarab}
        \textbf{\uline{%
                قواعد هامة:%
        }}
        \begin{itemize}[
            label = \textbullet, leftmargin=*, labelsep = 0.5ex, itemsep = 0\baselineskip, %nosep
            topsep = 0.5\baselineskip, font=\bfseries, before=\bfseries,
            ]
            \item الأول
            \item الثاني
        \end{itemize}%
    \end{txarab}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load `babel` with the option `layout=lists`:

```
\usepackage[english, bidi = basic, layout=lists]{babel}
```

`babel` assumes monolingual documents. This option readjusts lists internally to deal with multilingual documents.

Comment: Is it possible to **locally** increase the size of the Arabic font or upscale it in the specific list of `\begin{itemize}..`. knowing that the list is trapped in a `tcboxfit`?